# Workflow for driving Hive queries

Tags: frameworks, workflow, hive

Is there a good framework acting as workflow to drive Hive queries?  I looked at Hamake, Oozie, Azkaban, and Cascading but it seems like they don't fit this purpose.  I am currently using shell scripts to do this but it becomes messier and messier as we grow our business processes.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't paid much attention to many workflow engines but many people (including myself) use Hive client ( https://cwiki.apache.org/Hive/hiveclient.html ) to issue Hive queries from the language of their choice.

Answer (score 0):

Hamake is good if you want to run your hive queries when input data arrives or modifies. Oozie is good if you want to run your hive queries at a given schedule.